# What do I make my mockContext.Setup return in case of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, stored-procedures, moq

I am writing a unit test for a function which in turn calls a stored procedure using entity framework. The stored procedure returns null or integer. And I am trying to mock this part. I tried the following

```
mockContext.Setup(c => c.SP_DoSomething(param1, param2)).Returns(ObjectResult<int?> ???);
```

I would like to return 0 in my mock. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The class `ObjectResult<T>` is a sealed class without any public C'tor, initialization / setter methods.

You can use [PrivateObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) or to use reflaction, however both options won't provide an elegant / readable solution.

The elegant / readable solution is to use a code weaving tool such as MsFakes / Typemock Isolator; In following example I use MsFakes:

```
var queryResult = new List<int?>() { 0 };

var fakeQueryResult = new ShimObjectResult<int?>
{
    GetEnumerator = () => queryResult.GetEnumerator(),
    GetIListSourceListInternal = () => queryResult,
    GetEnumeratorInternal = () => queryResult.GetEnumerator()
};

mockContext.Setup(c => c.SP_DoSomething(param1, param2)).Returns(fakeQueryResult);
```

Comment: On Returns(fakeQueryResult), I get "Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Objects.Fakes.ShimObjectResult<...>' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<...>'

Comment: @user2027080, you didn't "fake" the correct type. You've generated a shim from the namespace `System.Data.Objects` instead of `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`.

Comment: Awesome, it is working now that I fixed that.. Thanks!